# PowerMockito: got InvalidUseOfMatchersException when use matchers mocking static method

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

When I'm testing this static method

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static long someMethod(Map map, String string, Long l, Log log) {
        ...
    }
}
```

with

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
//@PrepareForTest(SomeClass.class)
public class Tests {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        ...
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(SomeClass.class);
        Mockito.when(SomeClass.someMethod(anyMap(), anyString(), anyLong(), isA(Log.class))).thenReturn(1L);
        ...
    }
}
```

I got `InvalidUseOfMatchersException`. My questions are:

1. Why I got this exception when all the arguments are using matchers? How to solve it? I have debugged it, found the `isA(Log.class)` returns null.
2. When I add the `@PrepareForTest` annotation to the test class and run the test, the junit makes no  response. Why?

EDIT

I tried not to use argument matchers, and got

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
>   when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
>   For example:
>       when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);
>
> Also, this error might show up because:
>
> 1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
>      Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
> 2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
>
> at ...

So it seems due to the `someMethod` itself. There are **synchronized** block in the method. I'm wondering if Powermockito can mock that kind of method or not.

Comment: Kirin, my apologies.  I have deleted my incorrect answer.

Comment: When you say *"PrepareForTest makes no response"*, that may explain point *"2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object"*. Check the JARs on your classpath. I have added a minimum list of required JARs to my answer along with versions that work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the isA() to another any() call like this

```
Mockito.when(SomeClass.someMethod(anyMap(), anyString(), anyLong(), any(Log.class))).thenReturn(1L);
```

**[EDIT]**

Check your stacktrace when you get the exception. Are you seeing any `NoClassDefFoundError` reported? I noticed when I hadn't included the `javassist.jar` in my project I got a similar error to you.

I use PowerMockito and these are the jars I added to a brand new project to run the code that @Tom posted

- powermock-mockito-1.4.10-full.jar
- mockito-all-1.8.5.jar
- javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar
- junit-4.8.2.jar
- common-logging-1.1.1.jar

Always a good idea to check that you're using compatible JAR versions, and also check if there are any other conflicting JARs in your projects classpath.

Comment: Still throws the same exception. The `someMethod` contains synchronized code. Can't Powermockito mock that?

Comment: Yes, having a synchronized method will have no bearing on this issue. I have updated my answer, make sure you have the required JAR files installed in your project.

Comment: Oh god, I only imported powermock-mockito-xxx.jar and mockito-all-xxx.jar. I'll try to import others.

Comment: Still failed:( But PrepareForTest is ok now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never, the line below:

```
Mockito.when(SomeClass.someMethod(anyMap(), anyString(), anyLong(),
    isA(Log.class))).thenReturn(1L);
```

should be:

```
PowerMockito.when(SomeClass.someMethod(anyMap(), anyString(), anyLong(),
    isA(Log.class))).thenReturn(1L);
```

So, instead of invoking `Mockito.when`, one should invoke `PowerMockito.when`

Answer (score 0):

1. isA will always return `null`.  This is by design, it is documented in the Javadoc for the isA() method.  The reason for this is that null will always match the parameterized return type of class, which will always match the type of the argument in the stubbed method for which the isA() Matcher is used.  The null value which is returned is not actually acted upon.
2. Seems to work fine for me.  My complete test case:

```
import static org.mockito.Matchers.*;

import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

class SomeClass {
  public static long someMethod(final Map map, final String string, final Long l, final Log log) {
    return 2L;
  }
}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(SomeClass.class)
public class InvalidUseOfMatchersTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        // Mock the SomeClass' static methods, stub someMethod() to return 1
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(SomeClass.class);
        Mockito.when(SomeClass.someMethod(anyMap(), anyString(), anyLong(), isA(Log.class))).thenReturn(1L);

        // null NOT is-a Log, uses default stubbing: returns 0
        System.out.println(SomeClass.someMethod(null, null, 5L, null));
        // SimpleLog passes is-a test, uses stubbed result: returns 1
        System.out.println(SomeClass.someMethod(null, null, 7L, new SimpleLog("simplelog")));
    }
}
```

Perhaps post a complete example to help diagnose what's going on?

Comment: The `someMethod` contains synchronized code. Can't Powermockito mock that?

Answer (score -1):

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>${mockito.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I hope your project is using maven. Try including these jars to the build.

Comment: powermock-api-mockito-1.4.11, powermock-api-support-1.4.11, powermock-core-1.4.11, powermock-module-junit4-1.4.11, powermock-module-junit4-common-1.4.11, mockito-all-1.9.0  Try including these jars manually...