# Mockito - 0 Matchers Expected, 1 Recorded (InvalidUseOfMatchersException)

Tags: java, exception, mocking, mockito

I'm trying to mock up some mongo classes so that I don't need a connection (fairly standard stuff) but the following code gives me problems:

```
when(dbCollection.find(isA(DBObject.class))).thenReturn(dbCursor);
```

Running this get's me:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:
>   Invalid use of argument matchers!
>   0 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
>   at ...GridFileManagerTest.beforeClass(GridFileManagerTest.java:67)
>
> This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
>   //incorrect: someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
>
> When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
>   For example:
>       //correct:
>       someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
>
> For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.

If I were to do this though:

```
when(dbCollection.find(mock(DBObject.class))).thenReturn(dbCursor);
```

it no longer has that problem. This doesn't seem to accomplish what I want though - I want to return the value when the method is called with an object of type DBObject.

Thoughts?

Comment: See `[EDIT]` part of first answer. Maybe you got same problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828843/powermockito-got-invaliduseofmatchersexception-when-use-matchers-mocking-static

Comment: so is DBCollection a Mockito mock object?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think your results are compatible with the result that would happen if `dbCollection` is not a Mockito-mock (or your method is static or final).  That would mean that a matcher is being used where none can be used; hence the "0 matchers expected, 1 recorded".

Comment: It's a mock(DBCollection.class)

Comment: But (assumning this is MongDB) it looks like [`DBCollection#find()`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#find(com.mongodb.DBObject)) is final, which has the same effect.  You cannot mock final methods without using [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/).

Comment: It is indeed a final method, thanks for clarifying that for me!

Comment: I would if I could - I don't have the 15 reputation required.

Answer (score 6):

This same issue can be reproduced in Scala if you have default arguments. It may look like you're providing any() for every argument, but you should verify that the method definition doesn't have any default parameters which might be messing things up.

Answer (score 4):

In my case the mocked method was `final`. Removing the `final` from the method signature solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Probably unrelated, but I encountered the same error when I spied a package private method. Changing it to public solved the issue for me.

Comment: Yes, also had issues with package private visible methods.

Answer (score 0):

This also occurred with me when I was moving tests around and used actual object when stubbing instead of the mock