# Getting a InvalidUseOfMatchersException when stubbing a method

Tags: java, tdd, testng, mockito

I have this TestNG test method code:

```
@InjectMocks
private FilmeService filmeService = new FilmeServiceImpl();

@Mock
private FilmeDAO filmeDao;

@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun=true)
public void injectDao() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

//... another tests here

@Test
public void getRandomEnqueteFilmes() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Filme> listaFilmes = mock(List.class);

    when(listaFilmes.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(any(Filme.class));
    when(filmeDao.listAll()).thenReturn(listaFilmes);

    List<Filme> filmes = filmeService.getRandomEnqueteFilmes();

    assertNotNull(filmes, "Lista de filmes retornou vazia");
    assertEquals(filmes.size(), 2, "Lista não retornou com 2 filmes");
}
```

And I'm getting a "org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
0 matchers expected, 1 recorded:" in the call of listAll() method in this code:

```
@Override
public List<Filme> getRandomEnqueteFilmes() {
    int indice1, indice2 = 0;
    List<Filme> filmesExibir = new ArrayList<Filme>();
    List<Filme> filmes = dao.listAll();

    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    indice1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(5);
    do {
        indice2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(5);
    } while(indice1 == indice2);

    filmesExibir.add(filmes.get(indice1));
    filmesExibir.add(filmes.get(indice2));

    return filmesExibir;
}
```

I'm prety sure I'm missing something here but I don't know what it is! Someone help?

Comment: Is the `dao.listAll()` method final? What type is `dao`? You might be having the same issue as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458963/mockito-0-matchers-expected-1-recorded-invaliduseofmatchersexception).

Comment: @andersschuller No, dao is the filmeDao mocked object, I've improved my  question to turn this more visible. I've read the question you mention but nothing there clarifies an answer to my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
when(listaFilmes.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(any(Filme.class));
```

There's your problem. You can't use `any` in a return value. `any` is a Matcher—it's used to match parameter values for stubbing and verification—and doesn't make sense in defining a return value for a call. You'll need to explicitly return a Filme instance, or leave it null (which is the default behavior, which would defeat the point of stubbing).

I should note that it's often a good idea to use a real List instead of a mock List. Unlike custom code you've developed, List implementations are well-defined and well-tested, and unlike mock Lists a real List is very unlikely to break if you refactor your system under test to call different methods. It's a matter of style and testing philosophy, but you may find it advantageous just to use a real List here.

---

Why would the above rule cause that exception? Well, this explanation breaks some of Mockito's abstractions, but [matchers don't behave like you think they might](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891)—they record a value onto a secret ThreadLocal stack of ArgumentMatcher objects and return `null` or some other dummy value, and in the call to `when` or `verify` Mockito sees a non-empty stack and knows to use those Matchers in preference to actual argument values. As far as Mockito and the Java evaluation order are concerned, your code looks like the following:

```
when(listaFilmes.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
when(filmeDao.listAll(any())).thenReturn(listaFilmes); // nonsense
```

Naturally Mockito sees an `any` matcher, and `listAll` doesn't take an argument, so there are *0 matchers expected, 1 recorded*.

Comment: Yeah, man!! You got it!... I knew I was missing something and you just found it. Although I don't totaly agree with you in the "Mock a List" question because I don't want to test the List itself but another code that uses it and I don't want to feed this list 'couse this can become a hard thing to do in places where the list could get big in its size.

Comment: Glad to help! Regarding the list, it's a philosophy question, which Martin Fowler wrote about in his useful article ["Mocks Aren't Stubs"](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html#ClassicalAndMockistTesting). (The whole thing's worth a read.) You're welcome to keep using mocks of course—reasonable people disagree here—but beware that it can break your tests if you refactor your code to use different List methods, and it's always good to remember you have alternatives (Stubs, Fakes, and real objects) as options here. Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, I'm with Jeff (and Martin Fowler) on this one.  Any list is a value object.  It doesn't have "real" functionality worth stubbing or removing, so there's never any point in mocking it.  Just make a real list with whatever values you want it to have, which may or may not include mocks.