# Mockito throws InvalidUseOfMatchersException with ArgumentCaptor

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to use mockito's `ArgumentCaptor` class to capture some parameter and then do some verifications on it. But it's throwing an exception.

This is what is printed as the error message.

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
>   Invalid use of argument matchers!
>   0 matchers expected, 1 recorded:

Below is the code which is throwing the exception.

```
    //Arrange
    int amount = 100;

    DonationTransaction transaction = getPendingTransaction(player, amount);
    when(mockDonationTransactionDAO.getPendingTransactions(player)).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(transaction));

    ArgumentCaptor<DonationAttribution> argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(DonationAttribution.class);

    //Act
    donationService.applyPendingDonations(player, playerDTO);

    //Assert
    verify(mockDonationAttributionDAO).save(argumentCaptor.capture()); //Exception here
    ...
```

I am using Junit5 and mockito version 2.7.22.

Not sure if I am missing something obvious here.

My DonationAttributionDao extends an abstract DAO if that helps with anything and the save method is defined in the abstract class which takes as parameter the base class of the Argument I am trying to capture.

Comment: Is `donationAttributionDAO` a mock?

Comment: Yes. it is a mock. I will edit my question so that its clearer.

Comment: Is the save() method abstract or final? In this case you cannot mock it using Mockito and you will get the respective exception: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458963/mockito-0-matchers-expected-1-recorded-invaliduseofmatchersexception

Comment: Ahh, I see.. Had no clue about it. If you want you can write the answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The save() method is static or final. Thus, you cannot mock it. You can try to use PowerMock instead (see [Mockito - 0 Matchers Expected, 1 Recorded (InvalidUseOfMatchersException)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458963/mockito-0-matchers-expected-1-recorded-invaliduseofmatchersexception)).