# misplaced argument matcher powermock

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I am using mockito and powermock. I have a class named A with a static method B that takes 3 strings as in input. I get the following error

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: Misplaced argument matcher detected here:
```

Here is my code

```
// other imports removed
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

@PrepareForTest(A.class)
public class TestServiceA {

    @Test
    public void testA(){

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(A.class);
        when(A.B(anyString(), anyString(),anyString())).thenReturn("hello");
    }

}
```

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828843/ Also you don't have a `@RunWith` annotation so make sure the default runner is the powermock one